How to use git with new "Unified Vitis" IDE (Xilinx)
I have the same problem as this question but using git (instead of Mercurial) and also using the new "Unified Vitis", which is based on VSCode (instead of the old one, based on Eclipse). The old and new versions of Vitis differ a lot, which means that this question is not a duplicate.
Vitis (both old and new) "supports" git, at least according to documentation. However, I don't understand how they imagine this working and I haven't seen a documented workflow that's actually usable.
The old Vitis had an "import/export project Wizard". This seems to be absent in the new Vitis. This post in Xilinx forums says that the import/export feature is not yet available in new Vitis but planned for the 2024.1 release. As for user guides, UG1400(2023-12-13) in section "Source Control" explains how to do git add by clicking around in the Vitis GUI, but unfortunately not how to version control a project in such a way that someone else can actually use it.
I hope they find a better solution because, if I understand the workflow described there correctly, the import/export feature isn't very nice.
The fundamental problem with version control in Vitis...
... seems to be that Vitis generates a lot of files that have a lot of absolute paths. Even when using the automatically generated .gitignore, adding "everything else" to version control adds a lot of IDE-internal files that Vitis is constantly updating (even while the user doesn't change any sources or configuration). Furthermore, these files contain a lot of absolute paths, which makes it impractical to pull changes made on a different developer's system (the project will fail with build errors).
My current solution...
... is to version control NOTHING inside the vitis-managed platform and application folders. Instead, I use the Vitis Python CLI and copy over only the "magic stuff" (linker script, CMake files, etc.) that Vitis expects to be there, as well as an empty source file to make Vitis happy.
My CMakeLists.txt then instructs the build system to take sources from my original source directory. The tree looks like this:
"ROOT_PATH"
├── build-vitis        (NOT version controlled at all!
│                       Vitis stuff: "platform" and "application" folders.)
├── build-vivado       (Vivado output, e.g. the .xsa file)
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lscript.ld
│   ├── main.cpp
|   |    (more sources in a directory tree...)
│   ├── NOTUSED.cpp
|   |    (empty file, copied over to make Vivado think it "has sources")
│   └── UserConfig.cmake
└── tools
    ├── build_app.py
    └── ...

And build_app.py (somewhat simplified):
import vitis
import os

ROOT_PATH = <path to directory containing `tools` directory, user specified or deduced from PWD>

# This is the folder that "belongs" to Vitis.
# I put it into my .gitignore.
VITIS_BUILD_DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "build-vitis")
)
os.makedirs(VITIS_BUILD_DIR_PATH, exist_ok=True)

EXPECTED_XSA_FILE_PATH = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "build-vivado", "<filename>.xsa")
)

COMPONENT_NAME = "MYCOMPONENT"

MAIN_SRC_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "src")

client = vitis.create_client()
client.set_workspace(path=VITIS_BUILD_DIR_PATH)

PLATFORM_NAME = "platform_baremetal"
platform = client.create_platform_component(
    name=PLATFORM_NAME,
    hw=EXPECTED_XSA_FILE_PATH,
    os="standalone",
    cpu="<mycpu>",
)

platform = client.get_platform_component(name=PLATFORM_NAME)
status = platform.build()

comp = client.create_app_component(
    name=COMPONENT_NAME,
    platform=os.path.join(
        VITIS_BUILD_DIR_PATH,
        PLATFORM_NAME,
        "export",
        PLATFORM_NAME,
        f"{PLATFORM_NAME}.xpfm",
    ),
    domain="<mydomainname>",
)

comp = client.get_component(name=COMPONENT_NAME)
status = comp.import_files(
    from_loc=os.path.join(MAIN_SRC_PATH),
    files=[
        # Note: the actual C/C++ sources are NOT imported!
        "CMakeLists.txt",
        "UserConfig.cmake",
        "lscript.ld",
        "NOTUSED.cpp" # empty
    ],
    dest_dir_in_cmp="src",
)

comp.build()

This is called as vitis -s tools/build_app.py after cloning the repository (my actual script checks if platform/application exist and only update them if needed...).
Disadvantages
I don't copy over the sources because I want to be able to edit them at the location they are version controlled. I (think I) have to copy over the "magic files" to where Vitis expects them because I DO NOT want to use symlinks for compatibility between e.g. Windows/Linux developer machines. (Also, the liked question says that symlinks can cause problems.) This means that:

I have to "copy back" any changes (that I want to commit) made via Vitis to the configuration files (CMake, linker script, etc.) to my own src directory. The person asking about using Mercurial did this for all source code.

By instructing CMake to take sources from my own directory, I can edit them in Vitis (though I usually don't use Vitis at all when making major changes to source code) but it's confused and doesn't recognize includes/names any more in syntax highlighting etc.


Is there a better way?

Doesn't vitis have some readme or something about what you should typically version control?

@Kim not that I'm aware of, beyond what I wrote in the question...

This says it creates a .gitignore if you make a new project. https://docs.amd.com/r/2020.2-English/ug1400-vitis-embedded/Team-Actions steal that.

@Kim I mentioned in the question that this gitignore is not really useful. Also, you're linking to an older version of the UG1400 which describes the OLD Vitis.

I'm using vitis unified ide 2024.1, but the import/export is realized via .zip files, which in my view is unusable with git.
I solved this issue by generating 2 files within the appliction project that have absolute paths. I achived that via a python script.
The files in question are:

vitis-comp.json
app.yaml

I've added them to my .gitignore, copied the files and renamed them to somthing like app_template.yaml and added them to my version control instead. Then, I replaced the absolute path with a placeholder like ${workspaceFolder}/realativePathToFile.
I wrote a little python script that generates both app.yaml and vitis-comp.json for me that has to be run, when cloning the project.
For me, Vitis can now open the application project and compile the .elf file.
Advantages:

This way I don't have to touch my sources and CMakeLists.txt.
I can edit the source code in Vitis and the changes are found in git.

Disadvantages:

If these generated files are changed by vitis, you have to find the changes and have to adapt the *_template files accordingly. (a script could at least warn you that these files have been changed).
For more complex projects there could be extra files.

python script:
import re
import pathlib

def replace_in_file(old_file, new_file, token, replacement):
    with open(old_file, "r") as sources:
            lines = sources.readlines()
    with open(new_file, "w") as sources:
        for line in lines:
            sources.write(re.sub(str(token), str(replacement), line))

#replace ${workspaceFolder}
def replace_abs_paths():
    # I have placed my script in ${workspaceFolder}/scripts, so maybe you have to adapt it
    workspace_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.resolve()
    replace_in_file(
        f"{workspace_path}/application_project/src/app_template.yaml",
        f"{workspace_path}/application_project/src/app.yaml",
        r"\$\{workspaceFolder\}",
        workspace_path
        )
    replace_in_file(
        f"{workspace_path}/application_project/vitis-comp_template.json",
        f"{workspace_path}/application_project/vitis-comp.json",
        r"\$\{workspaceFolder\}",
        workspace_path
    )

replace_abs_paths()

app_template.yaml
domain_path: ${workspaceFolder}/application_project/export/platform/sw/standalone_psu_cortexr5_0
app_src_dir: /opt/Xilinx/Vitis/2024.1/data/embeddedsw/lib/sw_apps/hello_world
template: hello_world

vitis-comp_template.json
{
  "name": "application_project",
  "type": "HOST",
  "platform": "${workspaceFolder}/application_project/export/platform/platform.xpfm",
  "domain": "standalone_psu_cortexr5_0",
  "cpuInstance": "psu_cortexr5_0",
  "cpuType": "cortex-r5",
  "os": "standalone",
  "configuration": {
    "componentType": "HOST",
    "hostToolchainConfigurations": []
  },
  "domainRealName": "standalone_psu_cortexr5_0",
  "applicationFlow": "EMBEDDED"
}

